# gradle interactions with conda and pyenv

Tags: python, shell, gradle, conda

I have a simple gradle task which shells out to python to do some deployment stuff. However, it seems to use an arbitrary version of python in its `commandLine` call.

```
task deploy(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'build'
    tasks.findByName('build').mustRunAfter 'clean'
    workingDir "$buildDir/deploy/"
    commandLine "which", "python3"
}
```

yields `/Users/cchow/projects/<project>/venv/bin/python3` as expected. I have a virtualenv active when I run the gradle command.

However, the below yields something unexpected

```
task deploy(type: Exec) {
    dependsOn 'clean'
    dependsOn 'build'
    tasks.findByName('build').mustRunAfter 'clean'
    workingDir "$buildDir/deploy/"
    commandLine "python3", "-m", "yaml"
}
```

yields `/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/bin/python3: No module named yaml`. I do have conda installed, but conda installs should have lower priority than virtualenvs. According to `env` when executed via `commandLine "env"`:

`PATH=/Users/cchow/projects/<project>/venv/bin:/usr/local/Caskroom/miniconda/base/condabin:<rest of path>`

Why would it pick the virtualenv py3 for the former but the conda py3 for the latter block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've encountered this problem too and have found this as a workaround:

```
project.exec  {
    commandLine "sh", "-c", "python -m foo"
}
```